# Extracting type tag with Witness

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless, type-level-computation, jvm-bytecode

I'm running some experiments with `Witness` and now trying to understand how it works. Consider the following example:

```
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._
import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
import shapeless.Witness

def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(getTaggedValue("xxx" ->> 32))
  println(getTaggedValue("yyy" ->> 44))
}

def getTaggedValue[TypeTag, Value](kt: FieldType[TypeTag, Value])
                                (implicit witness: Witness.Aux[TypeTag]): TypeTag = witness.value
```

As expected, the program prints

```
xxx
yyy
```

I tried to understand how these `xxx` and `yyy` values were gotten and printed the actual bytecode of the `main` function:

```
    62: getstatic     #69                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
    65: ldc           #71                 // String xxx
    67: invokevirtual #75                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    70: getstatic     #69                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
    73: ldc           #77                 // String yyy
    75: invokevirtual #75                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

As can be seen, all of these `Witness`-tricks are not presented. The implicit `Witness.Aux[TypeTag]` came from 
[`implicit def apply[T]: Witness.Aux[T] = macro SingletonTypeMacros.materializeImpl[T]`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L40)

How does it actually work? Is it the compiler who optimized those method invocation? Or this was done via `macro`?

Comment: Are you compiling with the optimizer turned on?

Comment: @Jasper-M I did not pass any extra options to the compiler,..

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bytecode pattern you pasted. Neither with or without optimizer.

Comment: @Jasper-M Can you give a hint of what bytecode you got?

Comment: @Jasper-M and what scala compiler you are using.

Comment: I see calls to `getTaggedValue`, to `Witness.mkWitness` ... On Scala 2.13.1. On 2.12.10 I now see similar bytecode to yours. Very strange.

Comment: @Jasper-M Hm... I use `shapeless 2.3.3` and `Ligthbend Scala 2.12.9`. What versions are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the method call `getTaggedValue("xxx" ->> 32)`, the result type is the singleton type `"xxx"`. The Scala 2.12 compiler will in principle inline every expression with a singleton type to the accompanying value (for lack of better terminology, the "value" of type `"xxx"` is the string `"xxx"`). So in this case the entire expression `getTaggedValue("xxx" ->> 32)` and everything it encompasses,like constructing `"xxx" ->> 32` and summoning the implicit `Witness`, will all be erased to the simple value `"xxx"`.

Singleton types were reworked a bit for Scala 2.13 to make them first-class citizens in the language, and in that process inlining has been made less aggressive. Because if you would add side-effects to your `getTaggedValue` method you will see that this inlining is not always safe. Which means that when you compile with Scala 2.13 you *will* see calls such as `getTaggedValue` and `Witness.mkWitness` in the bytecode.